# Removing duplicated indexes with priority given by the value in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I can not find a way of getting this done.
I have a DataFrame with n rows .
Some indexes **id** are duplicated (repeated twice or more).
This is a simplified example:

```
>>> import pandas as p
>>> df = p.DataFrame({'id':['a','a','b', 'b'], 'test':['e','y','g', 's'], 'data':['re','rf','rg', 'rn']})
>>> df.set_index('id')
    test  data
id           
a     e    re
a     y    rf
b     g    rg
b     s    rn
```

I need to remove duplicate indexes to keep just one row. Dont mind if it is the first, the last or the middle one, except when the value in the **test** column is included in a list of preferred values.

```
preferred_values = ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

If this is the case, and considering my example, the row with the preferred value **y** must be kept.
Thus, a possible outcome would be:

```
   test  data
id           
a     y    rf
b     s    rn
```

I have considered `groupby` but I can not get the way to aggregate taking into account the condition of preferred values.
I also tried working with the dataframes created in the groupby process, like:

```
gb = df.groupby('id')
for name, group in gb:
    if len(group) > 1:
        print name
        print group
        # modify group here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your groupby approach. There may be an easier or more Pandas-esqe way, but this brute seems to get it done:

```
df2 = p.DataFrame()

for name, group in gb:
    if len(group) > 1:
        group['keeper'] =  group.test.isin(preferred_values)
        newindex = group[ group.keeper==True ].head(1).copy()
        if len(newindex) < 1:
            newindex = group.head(1).copy()
        df2 = df2.append(newindex[['data','id','test']])
```

There's some implicit rules in there. If more than one index is in the preferred_values list, it takes the first one. If no index is in the preferred list, it takes the first one. I think that lines up with your logic.

Thanks for providing example data, it makes things so much easier.